# Injecting a service in a springboot aws lambda

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda

I'm building a lambda based [on this code](https://github.com/laxika/spring-cloud-function-aws-example)

The uppercaseService is "injected" like this:

```
@Component("uppercaseFunction")
public class UppercaseFunction implements Function<UppercaseRequest, UppercaseResponse> {

private final UppercaseService uppercaseService;

public UppercaseFunction(final UppercaseService uppercaseService) {
    this.uppercaseService = uppercaseService;
}
```

This works fine until I try to inject another service inside UppercaseService.

```
@Service
public class UppercaseService {

    @Autowired
    MyService myService;

    public String uppercase(final String input) {
        myService.doSomething();
        return input.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
    }
}
```

AWS console returns:

> "errorMessage": "Error creating bean with name 'uppercaseService':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'myService'

This service works in a non lambda context. The class is present in the .jar built with maven package.

I tried the solution @ https://www.profit4cloud.nl/blog/just-spring-enabled-aws-lambdas without success.

Comment: where do you create the bean of `MyService` type?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn it comes from an external springboot project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to initialize your `MyService` bean first. Since your `MyService` come from external service which very likely to have different package than your own package

Either directly:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class UpperFunctionApplication {

    @Bean
    public MyService myService() {
       return new MyService(); // You must provide code to construct new MyService bean
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(UpperFunctionApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

or via componentscan:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = {UpperFunctionApplication.class, MyService.class})
public class UpperFunctionApplication {

    @Bean
    public MyService myService() {
       return new MyService(); // You must provide code to construct new MyService bean
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(UpperFunctionApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, It passed the bean registration but I get a java.lang.IllegalStateException: No function defined error now (and th project worked without the service injection)

Comment: As you keep a myth about your `MyService` so I can't help you. You have to correctly initialize MyService and all of its dependent bean in your library to make it fully work.

Comment: For the record, I needed to remove @ComponentScan because it was causing the "No function defined" error. Then to use the bean declared in this answer I needed an additional MyService myService = myService();